# get multiple values in array while loop

Tags: php, arrays

im having a problem in getting multiple values which i unload it from db and post to get all values by means of while loop but instead only the first value in array will display. here is my script:

**submit.php**

```
$res=mysql_query(select number from phonebook);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 $number = $row['number'];
}
<form method="post" action="send.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

**send.php**

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
exec('echo '.$message.' | mySmsGw --sendsms '.$number);
```

im trying to send message in multiple contact numbers and getting it with while loop but still only get the first value in number column.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If you want all numbers:

```
$number[] = $row['number'];
```

Comment: yes it will work when i echo it inside while loop but when echo it on post form it only gives me the first number in number column

Comment: So they don't loop the form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following line inside the loop:

```
$number = $row['number'];
```

on each new iteration $number value is over written. So change it to:

```
$number[] = $row['number'];
```

So that it can hold multiple numbers.

Comment: yes it will work when i echo it inside while loop but when echo it on post form it only gives me the first number in number column

Comment: So they don't loop the form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query("select number from phonebook");
$number = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $number[] = $row['number'];
}

<form method="post" action="send.php">
<?php foreach ($number as $num) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="number[]" value="<?php echo $num; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

POST:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$numbers = $_POST['number'];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
 exec('echo '.$message.' | mySmsGw --sendsms '.$number);
}
```

Comment: Why loop twice? And add some explanation and I'll +1

Comment: It's not necessary to loop twice but I just keep the original structure. You can just place the checkbox in the while loop.